# Not pulling document properties when moving a Document Library

Tags: 2010, 2007, document-library, properties

I'm attempting to move a very large Document Library from SP2007 to SP2010 but I cannot get the Properties of the Documents to move with the files. The library is too large to export as a Template with Data, so I've been attempting to move things over using the Windows Explorer Feature in both 2007/2010.

I've noticed that some Documents in the library migrate fine, but others dump all of the properties.

Is there a way I can completely duplicate a large document library without losing the properties of each document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the Content Deployment Wizard to do this?

http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

Comment: Does the Content Deployment Wizard need to be installed on my SP Server? It seems to immediately crash upon opening on my local machine.

Comment: Yes, you will need to install this on your SP Server. There should be full instructions on the CodePlex site.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer will pull over the previous versions of the file as long as the document libraries both have versioning on, but they won't retain the metadata properties to it. What I would suggest is make a powershell script to do the metadata pulling for you, but since you are going from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010, that might be much harder. You could write a VS application that will pull the documents in from Lists.asmx web reference, and post them on the SharePoint 2010 server programmatically.

Here's a good start on where I would look.

This article describes how you would retreive the items for the List: http://ojasmaru.blogspot.com/2012/08/sharepoint-2010-get-list-items-using.html

This article describes how you would post those items to a document library:
http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/10/19/add-new-document-to-document-library-in-sharepoint-using-c/